# Godot Lags out when preloading and freezes when playing on mobile

Tags: godot

I am currently making a tower defense game and i am loading enemies that i want to spawn in my waves. In my game scene i have an onready variable called enemylist which preloades all the enemies that i am instantiating in the spawn wave function.

```
@onready var enemylist = {"giant": preload("res://Enemies/giant.tscn"),"banshee":preload("res://Enemies/banshee.tscn"),"blue_behemot": preload("res://Enemies/blue_behemot.tscn"),"blue_tank":preload("res://Enemies/blue_tank.tscn")
```

when i start the game i expierience a long loading time which is fine by me, but the problem is that the game (my entire computer freezes) every 2 seconds, when it should be running smoothly. All the loading should have been done, however it just wont run the game normaly. Even worse is when playing on mobile. It crashes the game when preloading so i cant even see anything. The game runs ok when using load. But since i am spawing a lot of enemies and the enemylist has more enemies in them then i have showed here i cant dynamicaly load the enemies since this causes stutters. I am wondering if there is a solution to this problem because i cant find any hint in the documentary

i already tried just moving the loading to the actual spawning time, but this causes stutters and i want to get rid of it

Comment: You are correct, the all the loading should have been done. You need to investigate further the freezes you are getting. As per loading them dynamically you want "background loading" search for that in the documentation. That might solve the crashes. However, I do not expect that to fix your freezes. Perhaps the problem is associated with instantiating instead of loading? As I said, you need to investigate further, start with Godot's profiler, you should see spikes on the freezes, try to find out what is taking extra time there.

Comment: i found out why it lagged out. seems i had so many pngs in my game, that my vram ran out.